# Necessity to use present in a clause time (when)

Tags: future-tense

Are both sentences grammatically correct and what is the difference in term of meaning:

> Let me know when it arrives.
>   Let me know when it will arrive.

I think the second is better because with "know "you are not obliged to use present let me know when it will be here? He will be here on monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, but they mean different things:

- *Let me know when it arrives* means (approximately), “At that future time when it is here, tell me”.
- *Let me know when it will arrive* means (approximately) “Tell me now when you expect it to be here”.